# Prove the bounds on expected value of minimum distance

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random

Let $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$ be $n$ i.i.d. samples from the uniform distribution on the unit square $[0,1]^2$, and let $x \in [0,1]^2$ be an arbitrary fixed point. Prove that there exists some constants $c_1,c_2  > 0$ such that 
$$
\frac{c_1}{\sqrt{n}} \leq \mathbb{E}\big[\min_{1 \leq i \leq n}\|X_i-x\|\big] \leq \frac{c_2}{\sqrt{n}}
$$
*Hint*: Use $\mathbb{E}(X)= \int_{0}^\infty \mathbb{P}(X \geq t) \ dt$. No need to compute the constants $c_1,c_2$.

My attempt: Let $Y_n=\min_{1 \leq i \leq n}\|X_i-x\|$. Thus $P(Y_n \geq t)=P(\|X_i-x\| \geq t)^n $

But it's becoming difficult to analyze for what radius $t$ does the circle around $x$, leaves the unit square and compute the above probability. This is because we don't know anything about $x$. Can anyone help me with this ?